# Angularjs with rails API rest post 400 (bad request)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

Hello i making a project of rails api and angularJs,And I found the following error.

> angular.js:11821 POST http://localhost:3000/people 400 (Bad Request)

And I could not find why.

code below.

Rails Controller

```
 # POST /people
  def create
    @person = Person.new(person_params)

    if @person.save
      render json: @person, status: :created, location: @person
    else
      render json: @person.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

AngularJS

```
$scope.SendData = function () {
           // use $.param jQuery function to serialize data from JSON 
            var data = $.param({
                name: $scope.name,
                age: $scope.age,
                gender:$scope.gender,
                lonlat:$scope.lonlat
            });

            var config = {
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
                }
            }

            $http.post('http://localhost:3000/people', data, config)
            .then(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.PostDataResponse = data;
            })
            .catch(function (data, status, header, config) {
                $scope.ResponseDetails = "Data: " + data +
                    "<hr />status: " + status +
                    "<hr />headers: " + header +
                    "<hr />config: " + config;
            });
        };
```

Html

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="person">
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleInputEmail1">Name:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" ng-model="name" placeholder="Email">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleInputEmail1">age:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="age" ng-model="age" placeholder="Email">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleInputEmail1">gender:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="gender" ng-model="gender" placeholder="Email">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleInputEmail1">lonlat:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="lonlat" ng-model="lonlat" placeholder="Email">
</div>
<button ng-click="SendData()"
class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>

    {{ PostDataResponse }}
```

thanks for listening

Comment: Please post related logs. 400 error code mean a bad requests, when you send to the server a  request with bad formating. Check browser console logs and Rails logs for information about your request.

Comment: POST http://localhost:3000/people 400 (Bad Request)
(anonymous) @ angular.js:11821
n @ angular.js:11582
g @ angular.js:11292
(anonymous) @ angular.js:16104
$eval @ angular.js:17378
$digest @ angular.js:17191
$apply @ angular.js:17486
(anonymous) @ angular.js:25177
Rf @ angular.js:3487
d @ angular.js:3475.   In my chrome console

Comment: "status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"#\u003cActionController::ParameterMissing: param is
 missing or the value is empty: person\u003e","traces":{"Application Trace":[{"id":1,"trace":"app/controllers
/people_controller.rb:47:in `person_params'"} In firebug log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see your `person_params` definition, but if it is like when produced by rails generators, you are missing to wrap your params in a `person` hash

```
var data = $.param({person: 
    { name: $scope.name,
      age: $scope.age,
      gender:$scope.gender,
      lonlat:$scope.lonlat }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped me a lot. :)